# creating a DB schema with application.yml

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, yaml

so I'm trying to create my schema with the application.yml,
and it's just not working

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: true

  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    username: root
    password: 1234
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schema
      ?useUnicode=true
      &createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
      &useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true
      &useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
      &serverTimezone=UTC

server:
  port: 7070
```

Comment: Now I just created a schema not not the tables

Comment: Are you getting any errors? If yes, could you add it to the question?

Comment: no, spring application running ok and there is no SQL statements on console even though the "show-sql = true" statement in application.yml

Comment: It seems this was solved and is no reproductible as per OP's comment on the answer

Answer (score 0):

application.yml is not responsible for schema or table creation. You only set up your datasource connection here.

For schema (tables) creation, if you are using spring boot, you need to have schema.sql somewhere on classpath (for example in src/resources folder) and data.sql for import statements and such.

Alternatively you could let Spring JPA do the work which it does automatically for your annotated classes with annotations @Entity.

More here https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-data-jpa

Comment: I do have @Entity annotation inside the classes but still not working

Comment: please show the console output and also have you tried connecting to your mysql db? what does it show?

Comment: hi guys and thank you the problem solved just after I added the repositories for the entities and the tables created successuly. I guess it was the problem